# Hangfire and cosmos - how to enable container partition

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, hangfire

Question on Hangfire

1. How to enable the container, created by hangfire on cosmos DB to be partitioned by jobId?
2. Can the container be created before invoking hangfire?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're talking about `.net` and `c#` you can fairly easily create container using `CosmosDB SDK`. I recommend using *3.17+* as for the below versions there are some annoying memory leaks.

[Azure allows portal UI to create container manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-create-container).

Code snippet for creation of `jobs` container in `HangfireJobsDB`:

```
var client = new CosmosClient("https://<your account>.documents.azure.com:443/", accessKey);
var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("HangfireJobsDB");
var container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync("jobs", "/jobId", 1000);
```

Note, this snippet will create container with provisioned **1k RUs** throughput dedicated for it. CosmosDB [another model of throughput allocation on database level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput) which will share it across *all containers* in the DB. You should have at least 400 RUs per container in such model.

Comment: That example you give is using the .NET SDK v2, not the v3 SDK. Don't need the UriFactory anymore.

Comment: @MarkBrown, thanks for pointing out. I've updated the answer.